# Installed 16.10 how to keep old users

Tags: kubuntu

Just installed Kubuntu 16.10 in same location as previous Kubuntu 13.10. Created new user, doug, for the install. All went well. Created new user trying to use old user name, douglas. Saw icon for douglas but when trying to login get "X" cursor, screen grays then nothing happens. Have to reboot system using power switch no keyboard response. Logged in as doug. Directory and files in /home/douglas were owned by doug:doug. Changed using chown to douglas:douglas. Logged out and tried logging in as douglas. Same as before nothing seems to be happening. Reboot using power switch. Can login as doug and everything seems okay.
Guess basic question is what else do I need to do to get douglas to login? Thought changing owner:group would work.
Thanks, Doug

Comment: How did you change the ownership of the files/directory?  Did you change the owner of /home/douglas as well?  Did you change the hidden files/folders?  As a side note--use ```adduser --uid ...``` in a similar case and ensure that the new user (douglas) will get the uid of the original douglas.

Comment: Sorry didn't respond sooner. Thought I was supposed to get email when somebody answered my post.
I actually changed the .kde directory to .kde_old for user douglas then logged in as douglas and KDE created .kde and everything works as douglas. Of course, all the directories and files that were owned by douglas are now owned by doug so I have to change things around.
I did actually change owner for all files including hidden files.
I have been using Linux since 1995 starting with Slackware. Might go back after this "upgrade". Hate when distro takes away control.